# How to link library from dynamic to static without binary source code?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I want to know if it's possible for a library linked dynamically to another library to make this link static without the library's source code, so without any possibility of library's recompilation.

I suspect a library, linked dynamically to my application, not loading one of its own dynamically linked library properly, or too late, while the application is running, resulting in troubles.

That's why I want to make the link static.

I was thinking also to make the library causing troubles to link (static or dynamic) directly to the application. But the library would be linked twice. Sounds not good for me.

Comment: In short: No, its not possible.

Comment: In theory it is possible to mangle both libraries together in a single library, but practically there are no tools to do so. But this is completely irrelevant. Determining how a shared library is linked is not a big mystery. It is trivial to determine to which libraries a particular shared libraries is linked with. Either the shared library is linked with another library, or it's not. There is no vague, indeterminate, intermediate state. It should be possible to answer this question in no more than a few seconds.

Comment: Run the application in whatever debugger you use, you should get diagnostic messages telling you which libraries are being loaded in what order.